# Opencv 3.0 load cascadeClassifier Fail

Tags: android, opencv

I used opencv 3.0 to design an app.I loaded cascadeClassifier.And I used this function to check cascadeClassifier

```
cascadeClassifier = new  CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        if ( cascadeClassifier.empty() ) {
            Log.e("OpenCVActivity", "Error  empty");

            //cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier("/C:/Users/user/Desktop/project andriod/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/etc/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalcatface.xml");
        }
```

But When I compiled my app.It always showed "OpenCVActivity Error  empty" in the logcat.How could I solve this problem?(I use android studio 1.5) Thanks.

Comment: you really expect your android phone to find a file on your pc/desktop ?

Comment: Yes，I'm sure.I copied file path directly